# logging the data but not rendering p tag , why?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using firebase firestore and i fetched the data , everything is working fine but when i am passing it to some component only one item gets passed but log shows all the elements correctly.
I have just started learning react , any help is appreciated.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { auth, provider, db } from './firebase';
import DataCard from './DataCard'

function Explore() {
    const [equipmentList, setEquipments] = useState([]);

    const fetchData = async () => {
        const res = db.collection('Available');
        const data = await res.get();

        data.docs.forEach(item => {
            setEquipments([...equipmentList, item.data()]);
        })
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchData();
    }, [])

    equipmentList.forEach(item => {
        //console.log(item.description);
    })

    const dataJSX =
        <>
            {
                equipmentList.map(eq => (
                    <div key={eq.uid}>

                        {console.log(eq.equipment)}
                        <p>{eq.equipment}</p>
                    </div>
                ))

            }
        </>

    return (
        <>
            {dataJSX}
        </>
    )
}

export default Explore
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have problems with setting fetched data into the state.

You need to call `setEquipments` once when data is prepared because you always erase it with an initial array plus an item from forEach.

The right code for setting equipment is

```
const fetchData = async () => {
        const res = db.collection('Available');
        const data = await res.get();

        setEquipments(data.docs.map(item => item.data()))
    }
```

Comment: Great. Glad to help you.